# Chrome extension not loading properly after adding redirectUrl on webRequest.onBeforeRequest

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-webrequest

I am trying to develop a chrome extension using *chrome.webRequest* API. My extension will redirect https://google.com to https://stackoverflow.com. Functionality wise its working fine but after adding redirectUrl in chrome webRequest API my chrome extension is not loading properly.

Here is my **manifest.json** file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Test",
    "browser_action":
    {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "*://*.google.com/"
    ],

    "background":{
        "scripts": ["backgroundPage.js"]
    }
}
```

**popup.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Hello World!</title></head>
<body>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <input type="text" id="name">
</body>
</html>
```

**backgroundPage.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        return { redirectUrl: "https://stackoverflow.com"};
    }, { urls: ["<all_urls>"] }, ["blocking"]);
```

If I change redirectUrl in backgroundPage.js like below(No redirect)

> redirectUrl: details.url

the popup is opening properly. Like this,

[image: before changing redirectUrl]

However after changing redirectUrl like below,

> redirectUrl: "https://stackoverflow.com"

the popup is not opening properly but the redirect is working fine.

[image: after adding redirect]

Am I missing something here? When will these type of behaviour occur usually?
Thanks.

Comment: The popup is a separate page with its own URL and you're redirecting all URLs, including the popup's URL. Instead of guessing, use devtools debugger in your background page to see what's really happening.

Comment: Thanks, @wOxxOm. Your comment really helped me to solve this issue. You are right. The popup URL is also passed into the onBeforeRequest listener. so its also redirecting the popup URL to stackoverflow.com. Hence it's not loading properly.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem and solved it. You can replace the `onBeforeRequest` with `onHeadersReceived`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @wolf. It works but it's not the way to do it. By the time this event occurs there would be a call made to the URL which I indent to redirect.https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeSendHeaders